# Keys act like other keys, spacebar is f11, backspace is 4 etc

Tags: keyboard, java, minecraft

Windows 10

My keys are acting like other keys, enter is numlock, backspace is 4, space is f11, down arrow is f12, probably others too but I haven't found those yet. I suspect it has something to do with a minecraft java/optifine installation as it was not doing this before that. Same thing happened ~6 years ago when I was also playing minecraft religiously.

Uninstalled optifine and restarted my computer and it doesn't seem to be an issue. It only starts after I open a session of minecraft java, modded or not.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't seem to be an issue"? Do you mean the problem is resolved, or that the problem continues so Optifine is not tbe culprit? Have you tried a different keyboard?

Comment: There is absolutely no way a Java application that wasn’t running could cause the issues you describe

Comment: Easy solution - don't run your version of minecraft java, it might contain a virus. Find another version from a reputable source.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's PowerToys Keyboard Manager utility may allow you to see active key remaps. It will not help indicate the source of these remaps, and based on how the mapping is occurring, it is possible the Keyboard Manager utility may not be able to detect the remapping. But it may be able to give you more information than you currently have.

However, as you have already indicated this is occurring when you are running Java Minecraft, you already have a clear indication what you need to do in order to resolve this: download clean and valid versions of these products and discard the versions you are currently using.